# In a decorator how can I pass the function I'm decorating as an argument?

Tags: python, decorator

I made this simple decorator which basically puts the decorated function in a `try...except`.

```
from functools import wraps
def try_except(on_exception=None, exception=Exception, *args, **kwargs):
    from sys import stderr
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args1, **kwargs1):
            try:
                return func(*args1, **kwargs1)
            except exception as e:
                print(repr(e), file=stderr)
            if on_exception is not None:
                return on_exception(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Then, I tried to decorate the following function, so it calls itself if it raises a `ValueError`:

```
@try_except(get_int, ValueError, "Please enter a valid integer!\n>>> ")
def get_int(prompt=">>> "):
    return int(input(prompt))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\decorator_test.py", line 9348234, in <module>
    @try_except(get_int, ValueError, "Please enter a valid integer!\n>>> ")
NameError: name 'get_int' is not defined
```

I know I could just put it in a `while` loop with the `try...except` in the function, but I was doing this as a learning exercise. Is there any way to have this not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to define and use a **sentinel** object to denote "call the same *decorated* function now executing.  I.e, before the `def try_except`, add:

```
same = object()
```

and in the body of the wrapper, after the `try`/`except`:

```
        if on_exception is not None:
            if on_exception is same:
                return decorator(func)(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return on_exception(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, the decorated function would be e.g (Python 3, I assume, given the way you use `input` -- would no doubt be `raw_input` in Python 2)...:

```
@try_except(same, ValueError, "Please enter a valid integer!\n>>> ")
def get_int(prompt=">>> "):
    return int(input(prompt))
```

Comment: I think a good alternative is make it a string (possibly `"recurse"`?) and make that the default value for `on_exception`. Then, put it in the docstring and change `if on_exception is same:` to `if on_exception == "recurse"`. This, I think, reduces ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix that is with a function that calls the function.

```
def _get_int(prompt):
    get_int(prompt)
@try_except(_get_int, ValueError, "Please enter a valid integer!\n>>> ")
def get_int(prompt=">>> "):
    return int(input(prompt))
del _get_int

# Or even a lambda

@try_except(lambda p: get_int(p), ValueError, "Please enter a valid integer!\n>>> ")
def get_int(prompt=">>> "):
    return int(input(prompt))
```

Because the `_get_int` returns what `get_int` returns at the time of call (i.e. runtime), it will change to what `get_int` currently is.

You may think you would be able to do it without the `@` syntactic sugar, but that will only call the previous (undecorated) function, so it will not recurse.